# Injective frame homomorphism

Tags: logic, order-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be frames with bottom elements $\bot_A$ and $\bot_B$ respectively. Let $\phi : A \to B$ be a frame homomorphism such that $\phi(a) = \bot_B$ implies $a = \bot_A$ (that is, the kernel of $\phi$ is trivial).

**Question:** Does this imply that $\phi$ is injective?

Comment: What is a 'frame'? Is it a lattice?

Comment: Yes, a lattice with finite meets and arbitrary joins that satisfies the infinite distributive law. A frame morphism is a map that preserves finite meets and arbitrary joins.

Comment: So it's like the open sets in a topological space?

Comment: yes it is like the opens of a topological space

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest counterexample is given by the map from the three element linear order $\bot < a < \top$ to the two element linear order $\bot < \top$ given by $\bot\mapsto \bot$, $a\mapsto \top$, $\top\mapsto\top$.

Note that this is a special case of Stefan Mesken's answer: The three element linear order is the frame of open sets of the Sierpiński space $S = \{0,1\}$, with open sets $\{\emptyset, \{1\}, S\}$, and the two element linear order is the frame of open sets of the singleton space $\{1\}$, with open sets $\{\emptyset, \{1\}\}$. Now $\{1\}$ is a dense open set in $S$, and taking preimages along the continuous inclusion $\{1\}\to S$ gives the map of frames I described above.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a counterexample:

Let $(X; \tau)$ be a topological space with a dense open set $D \in \tau \setminus \{X\}$. Consider
$$
\phi \colon \tau \mapsto \tau \restriction D, a \mapsto a \cap D,
$$
where $\tau \restriction D$ is the subspace topology of $(X; \tau)$ induced by $D$.

Comment: Since I'm not familiar with frames, you should carefully check whether this works and let me know if there are any issues with my counterexample.

Comment: $\top$ is part of the data of a frame, so it has to be preserved by frame morphisms. But you can fix this by taking the codomain of your map to be the topology on $D$ instead of the topology on $X$. In other words, your map is the preimage map along the inclusion of $D$ into $X$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman Thanks, I'll edit that.